# How to fix Element and popper.js errors in VueJS web components with a shadowRoot?

Tags: vue.js, web-component, vue-cli, element-ui, popper.js

I created a web component with [Vue CLI 3](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#web-component) and [Element](https://element.eleme.io):

```
vue-cli-service build --target wc --name my-foo foo.vue
```

The component makes use of `DatePicker` and `Select` from Element, which in turn make use of some old version of [popper.js](https://popper.js.org) and [vue-popper](https://robinck.github.io/vue-popper/) under the covers. The Element source repository includes its own popper.js and vue-popper instead of using **npm** packages. The [popper.js](https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/blob/dev/src/utils/popper.js) file in Element just says `{{version}}` so I'm not sure how old it is or if it's been heavily customized by the Element developers. It doesn't look much like the [latest popper.js](https://unpkg.com/popper.js) file.

As it is, the included version of Popper ends up throwing errors when a `DatePicker` or `Select` are activated inside the web component:

`[Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "pickerVisible": "TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'."`

Running outside of the Vue CLI generated web component, the Element controls work fine. After some digging, I found that the web component wrapper that Vue CLI 3 generates makes use of `shadowRoot`, and the developer tools show `#shadow-root (open)` in the hierarchy when the web component is used at runtime.

Older versions of popper.js used to have issues with `shadowRoot`, but there is at least one [merged pull request](https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js/pull/74) from back in 2016 that addresses the problem. It doesn't look like Element contains a version that is able to work properly within a shadow root, which is surprising considering how long ago the issue was fixed, and Element being a Vue-friendly library.

Can anyone suggest a workaround for the `shadowRoot` issue without giving up style isolation, or a clean way to force Element to make use of the latest vue-popper package instead of its own included version?

Answer (score -3):

Forget about it. Use a better popover tool: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@soldeplata/popper-vue